# Snapshot dependency builds in the chain are not getting trigerred

Tags: build, teamcity, build-chain

I have defined snapshot dependencies in my build chain. For example:

**01 - Build Libraries**
    Trigerred by VCS

**02 - Build Windows**

- Snapshot dependency on "01 - Build Libraries"

**03 - Build Service_1**

- Snapshot dependency on "02 - Build Windows"

**03 - Build Service_2**

- Snapshot dependency on "02 - Build Windows"

**04 - Deploy**

- Snapshot dependency on "03 - Build Service_1" & "03 - Build Service_2"

Now, the last build in the chain is never trigerred automatically. I have to manually go and run the build.
Also, in the Build Chain view, it says the build "04" is part of the chain, but not trigerred. I am not able to figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It actually works the other way around. The trigger should be on "**04 - Deploy**". The other dependencies will get automatically built to satisfy the input requirements of "04 - Deploy".